# Filter out audio-only content on YouTube

Tags: youtube

When searching on YouTube, is there any way I can filter out videos that really are audio only and only has meaningless placeholder "watch paint dry" video content, eg.

- a single static image
- a series of images with the Ken Burns effect
- etc.

I realise this may be hard to define and even harder to program, but I wouldn't be surprised if YouTube has some sort of classification technology at least internally on what is actually continuous, full frame-rate live video and what is just some pointless collage someone put together.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't such a filter on YouTube to be able to pull this off. You can, however, use 3rd-party tools which can show you the list of all tracks YouTube stores given video file (eg. all quality video/audio/subtitle tracks)

[image: https://www.genyoutube.net/]

**https://www.genyoutube.net/**